# Can we bind size of ElementHost with its child control, so that we can resize it smoothly at runtime

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a user control and I'm adding to a WinForms panel in an ElementHost. I'm resizing my user control at runtime and want to bind its size with parent ElementHost.
Is this possible? Please provide solution if any.

Answer (score 0):

Set `DockStyle.Fill` property for `ElementHost`'s `Dock` property.